# Login Failed for existing user SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

Using C# I'm trying to connect to an existing DB in SQL Server 2012, from Visual Studio 2012.
I used the Visual Studio wizard to get my connection string, and I told it to use Windows Authentication (what I am using for my SQL DB, hosted locally on my system).
This is the error I get:

```
Cannot open database "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQ\DATA
\StockHolesDB.mdf" requested by the login. The Login failed.
Login failed for user '***\***'.
```

My connection string is `"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\StockHolesDB.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"`

Looking around online I saw that one of the solutions is to set that user up in the sql server. But that user **is** already set up in the server. A different username, but the same login name. And when I tried to add a new user with the same login name but different username it wouldn't work.

EDIT: I tried changing the DB name, and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enabled 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode' on MSSQL (right click on server, under security tab)